# pkg_resources.ResolutionError with python setup.py install?

Tags: python, setuptools

I used to be able to run the command `runner.py` from my module `my-runner` while using `python setup.py develop`. However, ever since that I reinstalled it using `python setup.py install`, I now get a `pkg_resources.ResolutionError` when calling `runner.py`.

This is the mini tree structure

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── some_other_file.py
│   ├── runner.py
├── setup.py
```

here is my `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my-runner',
    version='1.0.0',
    license='private',
    author='MyName',
    author_email='myname@myemail.com',
    description='My Runner',
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=['bin/runner.py', 'bin/some_other_file.py']
)
```

Running command `runner.py` returns the error

```
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/runner.py' not found in metadata at '/home/myname/module/my-runner.egg-info
```

I guess I have no clue why `install` would break it? I am guessing it has to do with the fact that `develop` does not read the `egg-info` dir but would like a solution to this problem.

Comment: I'm not going to make an answer since I'm not 100% sure, maybe it's just Python voodoo magic that's uncorrelated, but I've always had to uninstall the development version before doing an install. Which makes sense, because develop puts a path file in your site packages pointing back to your repo/directory and you need to clean that and other stuff up before you make the site-package with all the eggy-goodness. Hopefully it can put you on the right path if no one else comes in with a true answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to remove the package(pip3 uninstall my-runner) and reinstall it (python setup.py install)